# avoiding to go for next url until the category name has been unique

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, jsp

This is Jsp code here i'm going to validate my category name by using javascript and ajax when i press the submit button it will ask for category name in display fine but same like that i'm validating  category name unique by using ajax call it will check for unique when on bluer and first time submit button press when i press second time it will go to main url

```
<form name="frm" action="createnewcatgoryBean.jsp" method="post">
    <table style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 8px;">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">
    <div style="width: width:271px; color:red;" id="validate"></div>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Category Name<span>:</span></th><td><input id="cat"  onblur="return validatenewcat()" type="text" name="category">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Quotations form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="quotations"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Agreement form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="agreement"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Payment form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="payment"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>ETI<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="eti"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="float:right; padding-top:15px">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validatenewcat()" style="width: 60px;">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

*This is my ajax call script and javascript*

```
  function validatenewcat()
    {
        var category = document.getElementById("cat").value;
        if(category=="")
        {
            setTimeout(document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML="!PLz Enter The Category Name", 2000);
            return false;
        }   
        else
        {
        var url="catnamecheck.do?id="+category;
         xmlhttp.open("post", url,true);
         xmlhttp.send(null);
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
          {       
                 if(xmlhttp.status==200)
                  { 
                     var temp = xmlhttp.responseText;
                  if(temp!="")
                     {
                         document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML="!PLz Enter The Unique Category Name";
                         document.getElementById("cat").focus();
                        return false; 
                     }

                  }
          }

        }
    }


    }
```

This is my java code

```
public Map<String, String> catuniqecheck(String id) {

    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    String sql=null;
    try{
        c = JDBCHelper.getConnection();
        if(c!=null)
        {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            sql="select * from catgory where catgoryname=?";
            ps1=c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps1.setString(1, id);
            ps1.execute();
            rs1=ps1.getResultSet();
            if(rs1.next())
            {
                System.out.println("insdide of the catuniqecheck");
                map.put("catgoryname",rs1.getString("catgoryname"));
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.accumulateAll(map);
            }
            return map;
        }   
       else
         {  
               System.out.println("DB connection Established");
               return null  ;
         }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
               return null  ;
        }
finally{
            JDBCHelper.close(rs1);
            JDBCHelper.close(ps1);
            JDBCHelper.close(c);
       }
}
```

this my servlet code

```
System.out.println("inside success");
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.accumulateAll(result);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

when i press submit second time it is going to the other url  plz help me thank u

Comment: if i put return statement at the end it is working fine but once the validation is success it is not moving to the other url

Comment: If the validation got success you have to return true

Answer (score 1):

I hope This is the problem you are facing

```
<form name="frm" action="createnewcatgoryBean.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return validatenewcat()">
    <table style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 8px;">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">
    <div style="width: width:271px; color:red;" id="validate"></div>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Category Name<span>:</span></th><td><input id="cat"  onblur="return validatenewcat()" type="text" name="category">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Quotations form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="quotations"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Agreement form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="agreement"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Payment form<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="payment"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>ETI<span>:</span></th><td><input type="checkbox" name="eti"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="float:right; padding-top:15px">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  style="width: 60px;">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

use on submit in the form tag and not on click in submit type

Comment: can u plz help me out

Comment: may I know what's the problem you face while modifying the code as i said

Answer (score 1):

```
var cat_array = new array();
    var i=0;
function validatenewcat()
    {
        var is_dup_cat=false;
        var category = document.getElementById("cat").value;
      if(cat_array.length>=1){
       for(var j=0;j<cat_array.length;j++){
       if(cat_array[j]==category ){
       is_dup_cat=true;
         }
         }
       }


        if(category=="" || is_dup_cat)
        {
            setTimeout(document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML="!PLz Enter The Category Name", 2000);
            return false;
        }   
        else
        {
        cat_array[i++]=category ;
        var url="catnamecheck.do?id="+category;
         xmlhttp.open("post", url,true);
         xmlhttp.send(null);
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
          {       
                 if(xmlhttp.status==200)
                  { 
                     var temp = xmlhttp.responseText;
                  if(temp!="")
                     {
                         document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML="!PLz Enter The Unique Category Name";
                         document.getElementById("cat").focus();
                        return false; 
                     }

                  }
          }

        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: when i press the submit button second time it is going to the next url it is not properly validating.

Comment: cat_array=[]; blank your array before  next time used.

Comment: why i need to use array here can u plz look at the above code

Comment: we need array to store the previous category name.